# A morphism that is monic and epic but does not have a retraction

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I’m reading the Basic algebra II written by Jacobson

and I’m wondering In Top. a morphism that is monic and epic but does not have a retraction

But I can’t come up with some good examples, can anyone give some hints?

Comment: Try the map that identifies the endpoints of an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x$ from a non-trivial (not empty or singleton) set $X$ in the discrete topology to the same set in the indiscrete topology.

It's monic (as it's 1-1), epic (as it's onto), but has no retraction.

Comment: Thanks to your hints!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers and let $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ be given their usual topologies.

Since the topology on $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete, the map $f$ is continuous.

One easily sees that $f$ is monic and epic. There is no retraction/section since the topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ has no isolated points.